# python - Parse specific value in an HTML

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

Good evening my dear community. My question of tonight is following: I have this piece of HTML:

```
                      <option class="disabled" value="12_654" >
(EU 38 2/3 - US 6)                      </option>
                      <option class="disabled" value="12_3716" >
(EU 39 1/3 - US 6,5)                      </option>
                      <option class="disabled" value="12_636" >
(EU 40 - US 7)                      </option>
                      <option class="" value="12_634" >
EU 40 2/3 - US 7,5                      </option>
                      <option class="" value="12_462" >
EU 41 1/3 - US 8                      </option>
                      <option class="" value="12_460" >
EU 42 - US 8,5                      </option>
                      <option class="" value="12_459" >
EU 42 2/3 - US 9                      </option>
                      <option class="" value="12_458" >
EU 43 1/3 - US 9,5                      </option>
                      <option class="" value="12_457" >
EU 44 - US 10                      </option>
                      <option class="" value="12_456" >
EU 44 2/3 - US 10,5                      </option>
                      <option class="" value="12_455" >
EU 45 1/3 - US 11                      </option>
                      <option class="disabled" value="12_559" >
(EU 46 - US 11,5)                      </option>
                      <option class="disabled" value="12_454" >
(EU 46 2/3 - US 12)                      </option>
                      <option class="disabled" value="12_453" >
(EU 47 1/3 - US 12,5)                      </option>
                    </sel
```

it is just an example.... My goal is now to find the value of a specific size, by just giving the size. For example:

If I indicate my size is EU 40 - US 7 I want to be able to parse the value 12_636

I previously already used the bs4 module to parse HTML and to find specific values and I usually do it like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

soup=bs(html.text, 'lxml')
v=soup.find('option',{'class':''})['value']
```

but here, because with the method above there would be more possible values, it is not what I need. I tried about adding the desidered size in the tag I want to find, but it did not work.

```
v=soup.find('option',(EU 40 - US 7),{'class':''})['value']
```

It looked like this, but yes I know, it is incorrect. Now I have absolutely no idea on how to find the value, so I would be really grateful on any help I get. Thanks a lot dear community!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dict mapping each `option`'s text to its value, making sure to strip all the extraneous whitespace from `text`:

```
d = {option.text.strip(): option['value'] for option in soup.find_all('option')}
print(d['(EU 40 - US 7)'])
```

Result:

```
12_636
```

Comment: This works for me, thanks for taking the time for answering. Appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 1):

you could also use xpath and `fromstring`.

```
# import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring
# url = ''
# tree = html.fromstring( requests.get(url).content)
h = '''
 <option class="disabled" value="12_654" >
(EU 38 2/3 - US 6)                      </option>
                      <option class="disabled" value="12_3716" >
(EU 39 1/3 - US 6,5)                      </option>
                      <option class="disabled" value="12_636" >
(EU 40 - US 7)                      </option>
                      <option class="" value="12_634" >
EU 40 2/3 - US 7,5                      </option>
                      <option class="" value="12_462" >
EU 41 1/3 - US 8                      </option>
                      <option class="" value="12_460" >
EU 42 - US 8,5                      </option>
                      <option class="" value="12_459" >
EU 42 2/3 - US 9                      </option>
                      <option class="" value="12_458" >
EU 43 1/3 - US 9,5                      </option>
                      <option class="" value="12_457" >
EU 44 - US 10                      </option>
                      <option class="" value="12_456" >
EU 44 2/3 - US 10,5                      </option>
                      <option class="" value="12_455" >
EU 45 1/3 - US 11                      </option>
                      <option class="disabled" value="12_559" >
(EU 46 - US 11,5)                      </option>
                      <option class="disabled" value="12_454" >
(EU 46 2/3 - US 12)                      </option>
                      <option class="disabled" value="12_453" >
(EU 47 1/3 - US 12,5)                      </option>
                    </sel
'''
tree = fromstring(h)
print(tree.xpath("//option[text()[contains(.,'(EU 40 - US 7)')]]/@value"))
```